# How can I make Hls.js autoplay a video when its ready?

Tags: javascript, hls.js

I've tried to `video.play()` on listeners to many of the possible events, but none of them work all the time. I sometimes get an unhandled DOM exception in my console. Which event is the correct one to listen to, or how else can I achieve this functionality?

The events I've tried to listen to so far are

```
Hls.Events.LEVEL_LOADED
Hls.Events.FRAG_LOADED
Hls.Events.BUFFER_APPENDED
```

I'm simply adding listeners for these events like so:

```
Hls.on(EVENT, playVideo);
```

Hls.js: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js

Comment: Judging from this snippet https://docs.peer5.com/players/hls.js/ I would guess it is Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED which makes some sense.

Comment: @Countingstuff This doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried event `Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED`?

Example:

`hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,playVideo);`

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget you can no longer autoplay unmuted videos without interaction in Chrome.  See - https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

This works fine for me:

```
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
      video.muted = true;
      video.play();
    });
```

Comment: this also works for me!